# Memory leak with Killer Network Manager (e2400)

Tags: networking, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

## Context

I'm not really into hardware but my friend suggested I should try building my next rig and so I did (around a year ago). I've been totally unhappy with the result because of one problem - after downloading games from Steam I notice the computer slows down a lot and I've been living with this since I built this rig.

I believe my computer specs are well above and beyond what I need since I got an `i7-6700K`, `32GB RAM`, `GTX 1080`, and an `MSI Z170A Gaming M5 motherboard`. I actually started with 16GB of memory but when I first noticed this problem I thought it was just because I didn't have enough memory so I ordered another 16GB *(I'm stupid like that)*. Now that I have a total of 32GB it still happens. And since I didn't really know anything about hardware I didn't bother fixing it and simply restarted my computer after downloading large files to release the memory usage.

I grew tired of constantly rebooting my PC and I had a bit of time today so I searched for possible solutions and came across [this PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/3ryt7j/psa_if_you_have_windows_10_and_a_killer_network/) - it also links to another [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/369uwk/does_windows_10_have_a_system_wide_memory_leak/ctmr3lk/).

So I'm guessing the problem is with this software I have running on my taskbar called Killer Network Manager (e2400).

## Questions

- Is it safe for me to uninstall this software and just go with a generic driver from Windows for my networking needs? When I read about what the Killer software does, it seems like the only benefit I get from it is that it prioritizes network traffic for my games above other applications. I don't think I need that because I generally don't play online games when I'm downloading stuff.
- If I need to keep the Killer software, what can I do to prevent these memory leaks? Just download the [latest version](https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads) and hope for the best?

## Edit

I think another option I have is to simply uninstall the software and update the drivers? They have a [driver only download](https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/category/other-downloads).

Comment: Erm no judgement here, but you haven't downloaded games via torrent right? Run memory diagnostics, check the spec sheet for your sticks and make sure you are running them at their correct timing in the bios. You can run the intended drivers without the managment software.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I used to download games via torrent but that was years and years ago when I was a student. I don't have a torrent client installed on my machine now. How do I run these diagnostics? This is the part where I'm really clueless when it comes to BIOS and hardware. I didn't even overclock my 1080 because I'm afraid I'd just break an expensive part. What are these timings and how do I make sure they're correct?

Comment: Don't overclock unless you have water cooling or a superior cooling system. Its really not a good idea anyway, you will burn your parts out right. Start -> type memory diagnostics -> enter. Do you have a part number for your ram? I'm sure I could find the timing settings, but you failed to mention what ddr memory/speed it's was designed for.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart sorry took so long.. I uninstalled the manager software and installed the latest driver. I'm now downloading a game from Battle.net and Steam to test it out. I bought `G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2400` (x2) for a total of 4 sticks.

Comment: Have you tried updating the driver?

Comment: @Ramhound I have just updated the driver and started to download some games to test it out. I'm currently sitting at 10% memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up uninstalling the Killer Network Suite which included the Network Manager and the drivers.

I downloaded beforehand the [latest driver *(driver only installation)* from here](https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads) and installed it.

Downloaded games from Steam and Battle.net simultaneously and even played a game during the downloads. My memory usage is around 15-16 percent. After everything has finished my memory usage is down to 10%.

I think I can finally be happy about this rig I built.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yup, it tells me I can only accept it tomorrow though so I'll do that when I get the chance.